# recommended shortest path algorithm from edge to edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a board game for mobile application shown in this link: http://i45.tinypic.com/23u8u1h.png

The starting point can be any cell. the winner is the one who connects his/her vertically (green player) or horizontally (red player).

The nodes are the colored cells. The white cells can be considered weight maybe? I am not sure how to implement it, but when I think of Dijkstra algorithm, I believe that it would take a lot of time to compute till it comes with the correct answer when the board is in this state: http://i50.tinypic.com/35ivofd.png (I have to apply the algorithm on those four green cells)

I want an algorithm that tells me that " http://i48.tinypic.com/28c2ijl.png " black, brown, blue and purple paths are the shortest one within reasonable of time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're underestimating how fast computers are.  Dijkstra will be blazingly fast for this problem, with that small of a board.  You could look into A* as well, but *(even though it's ridiculously simple)* even that may be overkill for such a small search-space.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dijkstra will work just fine here, especially in conjuction with [Union Find algorithm](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find) used to connect fields adjacent to each other and filled with color other than white. Edges leading to white fields cost 1, edges leading to own fields cost 0 and edges leading to enemy fields cost infinity (e.g. *mn*). Then, you aren't going to run Dijkstra on nodes representing individual fields, but on *unions* of these fields (clusters of non-white colored fields).

Dijkstra will work here in approximately *O(mn log^2(mn))*, where *n* and *m* are dimensions of the board, and Union Find will work in *O(log mn)* time with simple optimalizations, mentioned at the bottom of the linked article.

Comment: Thanks @Zaroth, through my search on Union Find algorithm, I find out that my game is similar to Game of Hex. I am still not 100% ok with the algorithm, but if Dijkstra will work, I will go for it. The only problem I have is that sometimes I get multiple path from one node to another. The third link posted in my question shows that cell 3 has TWO path to cell 1. What should I do in this case?